# Understanding uart byte period with start bit, parity bit, and stop bit

Tags: serial-port, uart

I want to know how many bytes are transmitted in the second with some specicifc baud rate. IE, for example, I have a baudrate=9600, so I can send

```
9600 / 8 = 1200
```

bytes per second.

So, how much uart bytes can I send with 8bit + 1 stop bit + 1 parity bit?
Does it equal to

```
9600 / 10 = 960
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the start bit, it is 9600 / (1 + 8 + 1 + 1) = 872.

Comment: Does a start bit supported by a driver?

Comment: Not sure I can decode that comment.  Only the UART ever sees the start bit, the driver is not involved and there's no configuration for it.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Please wait while I make another question :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290866/9-bits-uart-emulation-with-dev-tty that's it